# I can't seem to get this function to repeat itself if the while condition is True

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is supposed to take a user's input for a value of 'n' that must be a positive integer, and if it's not positive or if it's a string rather than a integer than it should repeat the input process.  Here's my code:

```
def input_n():
    """obtains n value from user"""
    while True:
        print("Input number of terms n (must be > 0):")
        n = input("> ")
        if not n.isdigit():
            print("Not a usuable n value")
            return None
            continue
        else:
            n = int(n)
            if n < 1:
                print("Not a usuable n value")
                return None
            else:
                return n
```

I've tried it with and without the continue statement at the end of the first if loop.  It never seems to repeat itself if a negative number or string is inputed.  It moves on to the next part of my code (not shown or necessary).  Does anyone know why it's not repeating since the while loop remains True?

Comment: Whn you do `return None`, it already is back to the calling function. You need to remove that

Comment: Whereever the `if`s in the code lead you, there will always be a `return`. Also the `contiue` can never be executed since there is a `return` directly before.

Comment: @ kart Thanks! It worked :) I see now since the condition is True I don't need to return None as it will start the while loop over!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement ends the function.
So when you execute `return None` it cannot repeat itself in the cycle since it's already out of it.
You probably want to use `continue` instead of `return None`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're returning if n isn't a digit, which exits the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def input_n():
    """obtains n value from user"""
    print("Input number of terms n (must be > 0):")

    while True:
        n = input("> ")

        if not n.isdigit():
            print("Not a usable value - must be a number!")
            continue

        n = int(n)
        if n < 1:
            print("Not a usable value - too low!")
            continue

        return n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def input_n():
    print("Input number of terms n (must be > 0):")
    while True:
        n = raw_input("> ")
        if not n.isdigit() or n < 1:
            print("Not a usuable n value")
            continue
        else:
            return n
```